# How to embed CMYK color profile using Scribus in Windows

Tags: scribus

[Screenshot for Printer options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6L1g.png)Im trying to embed CMYK profile using scribus. The input file is in CMYK color space.

I enabled color management. I tried to save As PDF. In color tab i have selected output intended for Printer. When i tried to choose the color profile the ICC profiles for CMYK are not listed. Only the RGB profiles are getting listed.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what exactly is happening, since you're not providing many details.

But, normally, you should activate the color management and pick the right profile (not any CMYK profile, the profile the print shop told you to choose, the one matches their printers).

Activating it when exporting to PDF will technically satisfy the print shop's requirements, but you might just tell them to ignore the warnings and just print what they've got. It's just the same.

If you get the same issue, when activating the profiles for the document, you should add to your question the name of your profile and provide a link where we can download it.

Comment: Im trying to embed CMYK color profile ISO_Coated_v2_300%_ECI since the color space of the PDF im working in to is CMYK.

Comment: and how do you notice that scribus does not embed the profile? can you embed other profiles? afaik, if you enable the color management for the document and export the pdf with the default values, except for the pdf version and setting the target to printer, you should get the profiles in the pdf...

Comment: I will check whether the color profile is embedded or not using Adobe Illustrator. I can embed RGB profiles for the files which are in RGB color space. Please let me know the steps to embed CMYK profiles so that i can try that out and let you know the difficulties i am facing.

Comment: normally, you only need to activate the color management in the document's settings, pick the right profile and make sure that your target is "printer" when exporting to pdf.

Comment: Please check the attached screenshot. I have checked the image and it is in CMYK colorspace. I have enabled colormanagement and the printer option. But it is listing only RGB profiles. Even though windows color profile path has the CMYK color profiles, only the RGB profiles are getting listed.

Comment: as far as i know, you normally do not need to check that box... just export your pdf with a/ color management enabled b/ targetting the printer. what do you need is to pick the right profiles in the document settings > color management. (that list is probably for not converting RGB colors to CMYK but to embed a profile instead... but i'm really not sure of it)